# Есть ли альтернатива os.path.join()?

Tags: python, flask

Переписываю движок с WebApp2(python2.6) на Flask(python3.9). Встретился такой код:

```
verification_html = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(main.__file__),
                                     'templates',
                                     'auth/support_email.html')
```

Почитал [документацию](https://pythonworld.ru/moduli/modul-os-path.html#:%7E:text=os.path.join(path1%5B%2C%20path2%5B%2C%20...%5D%5D)%20%2D%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%B5%D1%82%20%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B8%20%D1%81%20%D1%83%D1%87%D1%91%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%20%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B9%20%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9%20%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B.) и предположил, что тут проходит проверка существования файла **support_email.html** в пути: **templates/auth/** и идет возврат полного пути вида **ДОМЕН/templates/auth/support_email.html**

Верно ли мое предположение и если да, то можно ли мне заменить это на **url_for()** или так и оставить и только **main** заменить на **__ name __**?

Comment: Тут нет проверки существования файла, просто работа со строками. В целом, альтернатива для os.path - модуль pathlib.

Comment: `и идет возврат полного пути вида ДОМЕН/templates/auth/support_email.html` - не идет, тут идет получение локального пути в файловой системе, не url. Берется путь файла модуля main, из него извлекается директория, в которой этот файл лежит, потом добавляется `templates/auth/support_email.html`

Comment: `os.path.join` - соединяет строки используя в качестве разделителя - разделитель директорий операционной системы. Т.е. `/` - под linux, `\ ` - под widows, `₩` - на корейской windows...  `url_for` - соединяет строки используя разделитель URL-лей т.е. `/`

Comment: Ок. Спасибо! Сделал так: **verification_html = os.path.join(
                                     'templates',
                                     'auth', 'support_email.html')**

Comment: @Chorkov, интересно, не знал, что на корейской Windows другой разделитель